# At the top bar "~1 suggested pending approval" is shown in spite of no actual suggested edit pending

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

Currently I've faced this issue. on Hinduism.SE I see 1 suggested pending approval:

[image: screenshot]

But clicking on which the page says:

> This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review, view all review queues.

Also review page says 0 suggested edits:

[image: screenshot]

Note that this is not issue that before I clicked on <kbd>1</kbd>, there was one suggested edit pending and when I clicked, it is already reviewed. Because I've reloaded page many times, even after 10 minutes I'm still getting <kbd>1</kbd> notification on top bar in spite of there is not any pending suggested edit approval.

Comment: It's just the result of caching, someone else got to the review before you did.

Comment: Does the issue still persist after an hour?

Comment: Could be an edit which you can't yet review, such as a tag-wiki edit. The number is cached, and the same value shown to all users.

Comment: @rene FYI: I haven't achieved 10k (that the question you've raised for dupe deals with) on Hinduism.SE yet.

Comment: The post isn't solely about the behavior of that number when you reach 10K. The only effect is that the difference becomes greater and therefor more obvious.

Comment: @rene I understand that the bug is due to caching issue as discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/260388). [ok; self voted to close as dupe]

Comment: @JonasCz actually OP here can [review tag wiki edits on that site](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), since it's still a beta.

Comment: Anyway, @Pandya  that suggested edit you saw there [was yours](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12859). It was not caching. Since you can't review your own edit, you didn't see it in the review itself, but since the same number is displayed to everyone in the top bar that's what you saw.

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh! ok; now I fully understand. Thanks for clarification!